# How do I transform query string parameters in nginx?

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, postgrest

How do I use nginx to transform incoming query string parameters according to some rule?  In particular, I want to prepend a prefix onto each and every query string parameter value.  In particular, I would like to do the following.

Given this URI:

```
http://localhost:3000/account?id=12345&name=bill
```

I would like it to be such that this is transformed into

```
http://localhost:3000/account?id=eq.12345&name=eq.bill
```

Where the prefix in each item is `eq.`  The reason is that I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for [PostgREST](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/index.html), and PostgREST has a [rich URL syntax](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html#horizontal-filtering-rows) built around operators like `eq.`, but I need to use it with clients who don't know that syntax.

I've looked into the nginx [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and the nginx [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) module.  The latter looks promising but I haven't yet figured out out to use it.

I did also try some lua scripting, to try to loop over `npx.req.get_uri_args` but at present I'm debugging the Lua code.

```lua
events {
}

http {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location / {
            default_type text/plain;
            access_by_lua_block {
               local qs = {}
               for key, val in pairs(ngx.req.get_uri_args()) do
                  table.insert(qs, key, "eq." .. val)
               end
               ngx.req.set_uri_args(qs)
            }            
            proxy_pass http://postgrest:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I answered my own question, though I welcome more input and contributions.  The following Lua scripting worked in `nginx.conf`:

```lua
events {
}

http {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location / {
            access_by_lua_block {
               local qs = {}
               for key, val in pairs(ngx.req.get_uri_args()) do
                  qs[key] = "eq." ..val
               end
               ngx.req.set_uri_args(qs)
            }            
            proxy_pass http://postgrest:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd love to know if there are alternatives in nginx to Lua scripting, but this seemed to do the trick.